# Why can I not do this?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

function name does not exist in the current context is the error it gives me. I want a dynamic ajax call.  Why does this happen? I get the handlers are processed server side, but I do not know how to go around this issue.

```
var getManager = function (functionName, contentDiv) {
    console.log("aircraft manager refresh called");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action(functionName, "AdminTools")',
        cache: false,
        data: {},
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#".concat(contentDiv)).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's not how it works. `@Url.Action` calls are invoked *server-side*. By the time your script runs, it was already replaced by a the actual Url

Comment: Just construct the string with JavaScript `url: "AdminTools/" + functionName`

Comment: I was looking at just placing the helper as a parameter, is it not considered bad practice to hard code urls in the ajax calls?

Comment: It's not the best but without more context this is the gist of the solution.

Comment: `@Url.Action()` is razor code and is evaluated on the server before its sent to the client. `functionName` is a client side javascript variable which does not exist at that point (it not in scope)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend you don't couple your server-side and client-side code like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action(functionName, "AdminTools")',  //THIS
```

It will turn into a maintenance nightmare.  Instead:

```
<div id="#contentDiv" data-url="@Url.Action(functionName, "AdminTools")">
@* content *@
</div>
```

then

```
var getManager = function (functionName, contentDiv) {
  console.log("aircraft manager refresh called");
  var url = contentDiv.data("url");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    // .....
```

if you decide later to have multiple *contentdivs* each can have it's own url, and your code is reusable.

Comment: Great Answer! Got my UpVote. For the sake of Clarity, can we remove the "functionName" param from the function construct? as in  "var getManager = function (contentDiv) { 
...........
"

Comment: This is more of an abstract answer, showing how to decouple the information.  If you need something specific for a problem you currently have, I highly recommend using the Ask A Question button.  Otherwise these comments will get too chatty about a question not on topic with this question.

Comment: No, working on a  problem I just thought there was value in removing the param (functionName) so as not confuse.... ;-)
Thanks for your response.